# Using C# Properties and JSON

Tags: c#, json, properties, accessor

I have this issue where I'm sending a request for a JSON Feed. The issue is that the feed has a dynamic header (i.e. when I send a request for "testinput1" the header response will be testinput1.

Therefore I need to make my RootObject dynamic, but I'm not sure how, could you please help me?

I've entered the troublesome part of the code below

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    textBlock1.Text = "Details Loaded.";
    short_description.Text = feed.testinput1.short_description; // can I make testinput1 a constant? its based on code below
});

public class Event
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; }
}

public class TrackCode
{
    public string short_description { get; set; }
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string tracker;
    public TrackCode testinput1// This needs to be based on user input each time
    {
        get; // Can I do something here to make sure that the "testinput1" changes each time?
        set;  // And create a constant that can be referred to?
    }
}
```

Hopefully I can do something like this:

```
     short_description.Text = feed.trackcode.short_description; // this is a constant


    public class RootObject
    {
        public string tracker = "AB123456789NZ"; // This is the variable that changes

        public TrackCode trackcode // this becomes a constant
        {
            get { return tracker; }  // uses tracking number as value for JSON when it retrieves it
            set { tracker = value;}
        }
    }
```

Where have I gone wrong? Thankyou!

Comment: Yes you can have your own logic in get set methods. You need not make it a const in set, can't you just access `testinput1`? Why do you want it to be a constant?

Comment: I can't set testinput1 as a constant as that is what the user enters in the form, which will vary each time

Comment: You cant I understand. My question is why do you want it to be?You ask for it in the comments. Anyway cant u directly access your property `testinput1`? What's the trouble you are facing when accessing?

Comment: my problem is I'm accessing a deserialised JSON feed, example: {
  "testinput1": {
    "short_description":"De",
    "detail_description":"DTT",
  }
}